# display list of custom objects as a drop-down in the PropertiesGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I want to take an object, let's say this object:

```
public class BenchmarkList
{
    public string ListName { get; set; }
    public IList<Benchmark> Benchmarks { get; set; }
}
```

and have that object display its ListName as the "name" part of the PropertiesGrid ("Benchmark" would be good), and for the "value" part of the PropertyGrid, to have a drop-down list of the IList<> of Benchmarks:

here is the Benchmark object

```
public class Benchmark
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

I would want the drop-down to show the Name property of the Benchmark for what the users can see. Here is a visual example:

[image]

So, essentially, I'm trying to get a collection of Benchmark objects into a drop-down list, and those objects should show their Name property as the value in the drop-down.

I've read other articles on using the PropertiesGrid, including [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/customizingcollectiondata.aspx#StartGoal) and [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/bending_property.aspx), but they are more complex than what I'm trying to do.

I usually work on server-side stuff, and don't deal with UI via WebForms or WinForms, so this PropertiesGrid is really taking me for a ride...

I do know my solution lies in implementing "ICustomTypeDescriptor", which will allow me to tell the PropertiesGrid what values it should be displaying regardless of the properties of the object to which I want to bind into the drop-down list, but I'm just not sure how or where to implement it.

Any pointers/help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

UPDATE:

Okay, so I'm changing the details around a little. I was going overboard before with the objects I thought should be involved, so here is my new approach.

I have an object called Analytic. This is the object that should be bound to the PropertiesGrid. Now, if I expose a property that is of an enum type, PropertiesGrid will take care of the drop-down list for me, which is very nice of it. If I expose a property that is a  collection of a custom type, PropertiesGrid is not so nice...

Here is the code for Analytic, the object I want to bind to the PropertiesGrid:

```
public class Analytic
{ 
    public enum Period { Daily, Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly };
    public Analytic()
    {
        this.Benchmark = new List<IBenchmark>();
    }
    public List<IBenchmark> Benchmark { get; set; }
    public Period Periods { get; set; }
    public void AddBenchmark(IBenchmark benchmark)
    {
        if (!this.Benchmark.Contains(benchmark))
        {
            this.Benchmark.Add(benchmark);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a short example of two objects that implement the IBenchmark interface:

```
public class Vehicle : IBenchmark
{
    public Vehicle()
    {
        this.ID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
        this.Type = this.GetType();
        this.Name = "Vehicle Name";
    }

    public string ID {get;set;}
    public Type Type {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class PrimaryBenchmark : IBenchmark
{
    public PrimaryBenchmark()
    {
        this.ID = "PrimaryBenchmark";
        this.Type = this.GetType();
        this.Name = "Primary Benchmark";
    }

    public string ID {get;set;}
    public Type Type {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

These two objects will be added to the Analytic object's Benchmark List collection in the WinForms code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Analytic analytic = new Analytic();
    analytic.AddBenchmark(new PrimaryBenchmark());
    analytic.AddBenchmark(new Vehicle());
    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = analytic;
}
```

Here is a screen-grab of the output in the PropertiesGrid. Note that the property exposed as an enum gets a nice drop-down list with no work, but the property exposed as an of List on gets a value of (Collection). When you click on (Collection), you get the Collection editor and then can see each object, and their respective properties:

[image]

This is not what I'm looking for. Like in my first screen grab in this post, I'm trying to render the property Benchmark collection of List as a drop-down list that shows the object's name property as the text of what can be displayed...

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In general, a drop down list in a property grid is used for setting the value of a property, from a given list. Here that means you should better have a property like "Benchmark" of type IBenchmark and a possible list of IBenchmark somewhere else. I have taken the liberty of changing your Analytic class like this:

```
public class Analytic
{
    public enum Period { Daily, Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly };
    public Analytic()
    {
        this.Benchmarks = new List<IBenchmark>();
    }

    // define a custom UI type editor so we can display our list of benchmark
    [Editor(typeof(BenchmarkTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public IBenchmark Benchmark { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)] // don't show in the property grid        
    public List<IBenchmark> Benchmarks { get; private set; }

    public Period Periods { get; set; }
    public void AddBenchmark(IBenchmark benchmark)
    {
        if (!this.Benchmarks.Contains(benchmark))
        {
            this.Benchmarks.Add(benchmark);
        }
    }
}
```

What you need now is not an ICustomTypeDescriptor, but instead a `TypeConverter` an an `UITypeEditor`. You need to decorate the Benchmark property with the UITypeEditor (as above) and the IBenchmark interface with the TypeConverter like this:

```
// use a custom type converter.
// it can be set on an interface so we don't have to redefine it for all deriving classes
[TypeConverter(typeof(BenchmarkTypeConverter))]
public interface IBenchmark
{
    string ID { get; set; }
    Type Type { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a sample TypeConverter implementation:

```
// this defines a custom type converter to convert from an IBenchmark to a string
// used by the property grid to display item when non edited
public class BenchmarkTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        // we only know how to convert from to a string
        return typeof(string) == destinationType;
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (typeof(string) == destinationType)
        {
            // just use the benchmark name
            IBenchmark benchmark = value as IBenchmark;
            if (benchmark != null)
                return benchmark.Name;
        }
        return "(none)";
    }
}
```

And here is a sample UITypeEditor implementation:

```
// this defines a custom UI type editor to display a list of possible benchmarks
// used by the property grid to display item in edit mode
public class BenchmarkTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private IWindowsFormsEditorService _editorService;

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // drop down mode (we'll host a listbox in the drop down)
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        _editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        // use a list box
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        lb.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        lb.SelectedValueChanged += OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged;

        // use the IBenchmark.Name property for list box display
        lb.DisplayMember = "Name";

        // get the analytic object from context
        // this is how we get the list of possible benchmarks
        Analytic analytic = (Analytic)context.Instance;
        foreach (IBenchmark benchmark in analytic.Benchmarks)
        {
            // we store benchmarks objects directly in the listbox
            int index = lb.Items.Add(benchmark);
            if (benchmark.Equals(value))
            {
                lb.SelectedIndex = index;
            }
        }

        // show this model stuff
        _editorService.DropDownControl(lb);
        if (lb.SelectedItem == null) // no selection, return the passed-in value as is
            return value;

        return lb.SelectedItem;
    }

    private void OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // close the drop down as soon as something is clicked
        _editorService.CloseDropDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simon, everything works great! I understand the BenchmarkTypeConverter class, but the BenchmarkTypeEdit class remains a mystery to me. It looks like whenever you click on the drop-down, the whole list has to rebuild itself and then choose the new value. I assume this is how the PropertyGrid must work "behind the scenes", and that's why doing something that is very straight-forward like can take a good amount of code. Either way, thanks so much for extending a helping hand! I'm much further along then I was before. Some good Karma coming your way! Mike

Comment: Some other great resources to explain what Simon did here. Again Simon, thanks so much!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171839.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx

Comment: Simon you've explained the concept very well and thank you for a very good and simple working example :) Cheers!

Comment: How to make the width of ListBox to be the width of the property grid? I have done it using your code, but ListBox displays with Width of 120 px.

Comment: @jstuardo - If listbox size is unspecified, it should take the width of the property grid's value column (with a minimum size if the grid is small). Otherwise you can set it's width manually. Or ask another question.

Comment: listbox size is unspecified. My listbox only has this in EditValue method: _listBox.Height = _listBox.PreferredHeight;