# How to add an existing control in another on properties panel at design time using C# WindowsFormApplication

Tags: c#, uitypeeditor

I have custom controls: `CustomControlOne, CustomControlTwo`.

My `CustomControlOne` has a `List<CustomControlTwo>` showed in your properties panel of my windows form application project:

[image: Properties Panel of CustomControlOne]

So when I click in the button, a window to add **new** items in this collection is opened:

[image: CustomControlTwo collection]

But, I want add **existing** CustomControlTwo items that are defined in MyForm. ps.: MyForm contains CustomControlOne and multiple CustomControlTwo.

I want this items can be added in design time, like same way that selecting an item in a comboBox (in CustomControlOne properties panel). When I change `List<CustomControlTwo>` to `ICollection<CustomControlTwo>` a comboBox is showed but the items of type CustomControlTwo not appears :(

How I can do this ?
How I can say to my CustomControlOne where are the CustomControlTwo items ?
Thx.

---

#### UPDATE:

I wrote my own UITypeEditor and I reached my goal with help of @Sefe and with [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171037/display-list-of-custom-objects-as-a-drop-down-in-the-propertiesgrid/5181847) link. Bellow my code:

```
public class CollectionTypeEditor : UITypeEditor {

private IWindowsFormsEditorService _editorService = null;
private ICollection<Control> mControls = null;
private List<Control> mPickedControls = null;

// Editor like Modal style
public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
  return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
}

// Opens modal and get returned data
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) {
  if (provider == null)
    return value;

  _editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService) provider
    .GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

  if (_editorService == null)
    return value;

  mControls = new List<Control>();

  // retrieve old data
  mPickedControls = value as List<Control>;
  if (mPickedControls == null)
    mPickedControls = new List<Control>();

  // getting existent controls that will be inflated in modal
  Control mContext = (Control) context.Instance;
  GetControls(mContext);

  // open form and get response
  CollectionDesign<Control> frmCollections = new CollectionDesign<Control>(mControls, ref mPickedControls);
  var response = _editorService.ShowDialog(frmCollections);

  // returning data from editor
  return response == DialogResult.OK ? mPickedControls : value;
}
```

Everything works well here. Now, my variable in properties panel:

```
[Editor(typeof(CollectionTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ActionButtonConverter))]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<Control> ActionButtons { get; set; }
```

The serialization attribute was added because the file couldn't be saved. When form is closed and reopened, all data are lost.

The stranger thing is that I wrote other UITypeEditor like the **same way**, just changing type of data to `string` and I can close or reopen my form and all works fine, the data are saved.

I already added a TypeConverter but I think that isn't case here. what is wrong with my code?

My basic setup:
[image: My basic setup]

In this setup, `BaseForm` extends Form. With string works, but with List data are lost on close form or build project...

**Resumed workflow:**

1 - Open MyForm.
    2 - Click at ActionButtons ellipsis [...] (inherited by BaseForm) on MyForm properties panel.
    3 - A custom form is opened with inflated objects that I want pick.
    4 - Objects that I want are picked and I close form. So now, data is ok cause I can reopen that form and see objects that I picked.
    5 - Now when close the MyForm and reopen it, all data are lost. The same thing happens when build the project. But if I do all this steps with a string, all are Ok (data are saved).

Thanks all, and sorry for bad language :P

Comment: You have to add the custom control to the ICollection.

Comment: I found this solution too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171037/display-list-of-custom-objects-as-a-drop-down-in-the-propertiesgrid/5181847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add multiple `CustomControlTwo` items to your control, a drop down list will do you no good, since you can only select one value there.

If you are able to change the property to accept a single instance of `CustomControlTwo` (or are OK that the list you can create in your property browser has only one item), you can create a new [`System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) that will create the list to select from. A type converter is an abstract class and you will have to implement a couple of abstract methods. The methods that are valuable to you are `GetStandardValuesSupported`, `GetStandardValuesExclusive` and `GetStandardValues`. Here is the part that is interesting to you (you have to add the other methods):

```
public class CustomControlOneConverter : TypeConverter {
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        //By returning true, you tell the property designer to add a drop down list
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        //By returning true, you tell the property designer to not allow the user to enter his own text
        return true;
    }


    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        //Get all objects of type CustomControlTwo from the container
        CustomControlTwo[] controlsToList =
            context.Container.Components.OfType<CustomControlTwo>().ToArray;

        //Return a collection of the controls
        return new StandardValuesCollection(controlsToList);
    }

    //implement the other abstract methods
}
```

What you do in `GetStandardValues` is to search in the container of `CustomControlOne`, if there are instances of `CustomControlTwo`. Those are then added to the list of standard values to select from in the property browser.

If you are **not** able to change your property to select only one `CustomControlTwo`, you will need to create your own UI to display when the ellipsis (...) is clicked in your property window. For that you need to create your own [`UITypeEditor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor(v=vs.110).aspx). That, however is a more complex undertaking and is not easily explained in a nutshell.

Comment: @Safe Now I have my own UITypeEditor with modal interface that adds and returns right value. But now, every time that I make a build/rebuild my project, all data are lost. What am I forgetting ? I want to attach this data to my property in design time and reuse it on runtime...

Comment: That is hard to tell without seeing the code. You might need a serializer or something else. If you open another question about that, I could take a look at it (or someone else who is faster).

Comment: I think you should transfer the update block to a new question, because I think it's a new issue. Anyway, four your new problem you should look into the TypeConverter. Does it convert from and to string?

Comment: Hi, moving Update section to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921778/how-to-save-collection-data-in-design-time-with-custom-uitypeeditor-c-sharp-wind. **About typeConverter:** I did extend methods `CanConvertTo` returning if destinationType was equal `List<Control>` AND `ConvertTo` returning `value` casted to `List<Control` otherwise "(none)".

Comment: Now my List of controls are stored in myForm when it's closed or reopened. But the controls don't are attached on property grid. i.e. If I click on ellipsis [...] the that values stored aren't passed to property `value` from `EditValue` method. I'm feeling that it close :)