# Tell UITypeEditor a code pattern to insert in .Designer.cs

Tags: c#, designer, propertygrid

I have a class `MyProperty` which works like an `enum`, but with static objects, and I created a dropdown `UITypeEditor` for the property grid.

[MyProperty.cs]

```cs
[Editor(typeof(MyPropertyEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public class MyProperty
{
    public static MyProperty item1=new MyProperty("name1",value1);
    public static MyProperty item2=new MyProperty("name2",value2);
    // ...

    public MyProperty(string name,int value) {Name=name; Value=value;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Value {get; private set;}

    public static List<MyProperty> list=SelectPublicStaticMyPropertyFields();

    public override string ToString() {return Name;}
}
```

[MyPropertyEditor.cs]

```
public class MyPropertyEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService;

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {           
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {            
        editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        ListBox l = new ListBox
        {
            SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One
        };           
        l.SelectedValueChanged += OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged;

        l.DisplayMember = "Name";           
        l.ValueMember = "Name";           
        l.DataSource = MyProperty.list;           

        editorService.DropDownControl(lb);                   
        return l.SelectedItem;
    }

    private void OnListBoxSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        editorService.CloseDropDown();
    }      
}
```

[MyControl.cs]

```cs
public partial class MyControl:UserControl
{
     public MyControl()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     public MyProperty MyProperty {get; set;}
}
```

This works properly at design time. The problem is that the `MyControl.Designer.cs` file doesn't save the changes from the property grid.
It should contain something like this:

[MyControl.Designer.cs]

```cs
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyControl
            //            
            this.Name = "MyControl";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(133, 60);
            base.Multiline = false;
            ///this one doesn't appear:
            this.MyProperty=MyProperty.item1 //or item2, ...
            ///
            this.Value = Color.Transparent;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

Also, the `MyProperty` has the default value at runtime, even if at design time it seems to have changed.

What should I do?

Comment: We don't know anything about the control, having two classes named MyProperty and the first one not deriving from Control doesn't help us help you.  Full example [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181847/17034).

Comment: This is a useful example, but didn't solve my problem. I corrected my question by adding the control class. The property is shown in the grid, I can freely use the dropdown, but the changes doesn't affect the control when I build it.

Comment: I did more research on my issue and I found that what I want is called "serialization" to designer or somthing like that, but I don't understand very much of this concept.